# How are zsh autocompletions for commands with subcommands defined?

Tags: zsh, zsh-completion

I am trying to write a tab-completion script for [borg](https://www.borgbackup.org/).

So far, I have managed to define completions for `borg` itself, as well as `borg key` with its subcommands and `borg benchmark` with its singular subcommand. However, I am now trying to define completion for `borg init` and I am having trouble.

The issue presents itself *only* when I define two arguments under the `borg init` command to use the same description text; i.e. both `-e` and `--encryption` should use the same description, as they are practically the same argument. This has worked fine for `borg`'s arguments, but now it breaks.

This is my code, slightly redacted to spare you the redundancy:

```
compdef _borg borg

function _borg {
    local line ret=1
    local -a argus

    local logs="--critical --error --warning --debug --info -v --verbose"

    argus+=(
        "(*)"{-h,--help}"[Show help and exit]"
        "(*)-V[Show Borg version and exit]"
        "($logs)--critical[Work on log level CRITICAL]"
        "($logs)--error[Work on log level ERROR]"
        "($logs)--warning[Work on log level WARNING (default)]"
        "($logs)"{--info,-v,--verbose}"[Work on log level INFO]"
        "($logs)--debug[Enable debug output; log level DEBUG]"
        {-p,--progress}"[Show progress]"
        "--log-json[Output one JSON object per log line instead of formatted text]"
        "--show-version[Show/log borg version]"
        "--show-rc[Show/log returncode]"
        "--consider-part-files[treat part files like normal files (e.g. to list/extract them)]"
        "--lock-wait[Wait at most SECONDS for acquiring a repository/cache lock (default 1)]:SECONDS:()"
        "--umask[Set umask to M (local and remote; default 0077)]:M (umask value, e.g. 0077):()"
        "--remote-path[Use PATH as borg executable on the remote (default: \"borg\")]:PATH:()"
        "--remote-ratelimit[Set remote network upload rate limit in kiByte/s (default: 0=unlimited)]:RATE:()"
        "--debug-profile[Write execution profile in Borg format into FILE.]:FILE:_files"
        "--rsh[Use this command to connect to the \"borg serve\" process (default: \"ssh\")]:RSH:()"
        "1: :((init\:\"Initialize a new repository\" \
                create\:\"Create a new archive\" \
                extract\:\"Extract the contents of an archive\" \
                check\:\"Verifies consistency of a repository and its archives\" \
                rename\:\"Renames an archive in a repository\" \
                list\:\"Lists contents of a repository or archive\" \
                diff\:\"Finds differences between archives\" \
                delete\:\"Deletes an archive or an entire repository (and its cache)\" \
                prune\:\"Prunes a repository\" \
                info\:\"Shows info about a repository or archive\" \
                mount\:\"Mounts an archive as a FUSE filesystem\" \
                unmount\:\"Unmounts a FUSE filesystem mounted with \\\"borg mount\\\"\" \
                key\:\"Keyword for key-related functions\" \
                upgrade\:\"Upgrade a local Borg repository\" \
                recreate\:\"EXPERIMENTAL: Recreates contents of existing archives\" \
                export-tar\:\"Creates a tarball from an archive\" \
                serve\:\"Starts repository server process. Not usually used manually.\" \
                config\:\"Gets and sets options in local repository and cache config files\" \
                with-lock\:\"Executes another command with the repository lock held\" \
                break-lock\:\"Breaks the repository and cache locks\" \
                benchmark\:\"Keyword for the benchmark function\"))" \
        "*::arg:->args"
    )

    _arguments -w -s -S -C $argus[@] && ret=0

    case $line[1] in
        benchmark)
            _borg_benchmark
            ;;
        init)
            _borg_init
            ;;
        key)
            _borg_key
            ;;
    esac
    return ret
}

function _borg_benchmark {
# stuff
}

function _borg_benchmark_crud {
# stuff again
}

function _borg_init {
    local line ret=1
    local -a argus

    argus+=(
        "-t[This is a test]"
        "--test[This is a test]"
        "(--append-only)--append-only[Create an append-only mode repository]"
        "*::arg:->args"
    )

    _arguments -w -s -S -C $argus[@] && ret=0

    return ret
}

function _borg_key {
# key stuff
}

function _borg_key_changepassphrase {
# stuff
}

function _borg_key_export {
# more stuff
}

function _borg_key_import {
# other stuff
}
```

If I try to tab-complete `borg init -` using this setup, I get the following output:

```
$ borg init -
Completing option
--append-only                                              
--test                                                     

-t                                                         
-- Create an append-only mode repository                   
-- This is a test                                          
--append-only                                              
--test                                                     

-t                                                         
-- Create an append-only mode repository                   
-- This is a test                                          
--append-only                                              
--test                                                     

-t                                                         
-- Create an append-only mode repository                   
-- This is a test                                          
--append-only                                              
--test                                                     

-t                                                         
-- Create an append-only mode repository                   
-- This is a test
```

The completion appears to forget what tabs are and repeats itself four times. If I change `--test[This is a test]` to `--test[This is another test]` in `_borg_init`, I instead get the following completion:

```
$ borg init -
Completing option
--append-only  -- Create an append-only mode repository
--test         -- This is another test
-t             -- This is a test
```

The above is "correct", in the sense that it's not broken, but I cannot seem to define arguments that share a description in a subcommand. How should I do that? And, more generally, how are you *supposed* to define completions for commands with subcommands (which may, in turn, have more arguments)?

Comment: I don't know much about `zsh`, I've never tried to do what you are doing and I use a different shell, but to help you debug I notice one disrepancy: looking at your first snippet of code I see `{-p,--progress}` and so I'd expect this in your `_borg_init`-function `{-t,--test}`. https://sourceforge.net/p/zsh/code/ci/master/tree/Completion/Unix/Command/_git has this consistency (line 57 and 8130 for example)

Comment: @FilipAllberg Unfortunately, using the `{-t,--test}` syntax gives the exact same error.